# Docker compose --detached (-d) not detaching right away

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file that has 2 services. Service B depends on Service A using a health check. Service A takes about 30s to start up.

The problem I'm having is, I'd like to start up the services and move on with my day without blocking the terminal.

I've tried `docker compose up -d` - but it still waits for the 2 services to startup before giving back the terminal.

Is there any way to detach right away?

Comment: Tried the "background operator"?? (In Unix based systems: `&`..in windows more like: `start /B "" docker ...` https://superuser.com/a/341603/107659)?

Comment: should have specified, this is in linux

Comment: You only have 1 terminal?